# Guardar contacto vCard en la agenda del móvil y llamar a una función php desde JS

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Estoy haciendo una vCard, y quiero implementar un botón, el cual me recoja de la base de datos y me guarde directamente en la agenda del móvil, el contacto. Estoy mirando por todos lados y no encuentro información sobre este tema. Sabéis cómo o qué necesitaría para hace eso? Es una web desarrollada en php y JS.
De momento he creado la siguiente función al que lo llamo desde un botón:

```javascript
function guardarContacto() {

    fetch('../../main.php?action=obtenerDatosVCard')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(datos => {
        // Aquí puedes acceder a los datos en formato JSON en la variable `data`
        var nombre = datos.nombre;
        var apellidos = datos.apellidos;
        var email = datos.email;
        var telefono = datos.telefono;
        var empresa = datos.empresa;
        var direccion = datos.direccion;
        var web = datos.web;
        var linkedin = datos.linkedin;
        var instagram = datos.instagram;
        var facebook = datos.facebook;
        var twitter = datos.twitter;
        var fperfil = datos.fperfil;
        var logo = datos.logo;

        // Construir la cadena de texto en formato vCard
        var vcard = "BEGIN:VCARD\r\n";
        vcard += "VERSION:3.0\r\n";
        vcard += "N:" + apellidos + ";" + nombre + ";;;\r\n";
        vcard += "FN:" + nombre + " " + apellidos + "\r\n";
        vcard += "ORG:" + empresa + "\r\n";
        vcard += "TEL;TYPE=WORK,VOICE:" + telefono + "\r\n";
        vcard += "ADR;TYPE=WORK:;;" + direccion + ";;;;\r\n";
        vcard += "EMAIL:" + email + "\r\n";
        vcard += "URL;TYPE=WORK:" + web + "\r\n";
        vcard += "URL;TYPE=LINKEDIN:" + linkedin + "\r\n";
        vcard += "URL;TYPE=INSTAGRAM:" + instagram + "\r\n";
        vcard += "URL;TYPE=FACEBOOK:" + facebook + "\r\n";
        vcard += "URL;TYPE=TWITTER:" + twitter + "\r\n";
        vcard += "PHOTO;TYPE=JPEG;ENCODING=BASE64:" + logo + "\r\n";
        vcard += "END:VCARD\r\n";

        // Crear un enlace de descarga con la cadena de texto de la vCard
        var blob = new Blob([vcard], { type: "text/vcard" });
        var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        var link = document.createElement("a");
        link.setAttribute("href", url);
        link.setAttribute("download", "contacto.vcf");

        // Hacer clic en el enlace para descargar el archivo
        link.click();

        // Liberar el objeto URL y eliminar el enlace
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
        link.parentNode.removeChild(link);
    });
    
}
```

La función se supone que se encarga de llamara una función que tengo en main.php y que se llama obtenerDatosVCard(), el cual devuelve un json con todo los datos. Recoge esos datos y genera una VCard para luego poder descargarla. Sin embargo el fetch para recoger los datos no funciona. No sé cómo debería ser exactmente la llamada, pero he probado también con http y nada.
Entonces la cosa es cómo puedo, llamar a una función del archivo php que devuelve un json, interpretarla desde el JS, recorrerlas y almacenarlas en nuevas variables.

Dejo también la función del php:

```
include_once("BD/conexion.php");
        $id = $_REQUEST['id_unico'];
        $sql = mysqli_query($conexionbd, "SELECT * FROM tarjeta WHERE id_unico = {$id}");
        if(mysqli_num_rows($sql)>0){
            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);

            $nombre = $row['nombre'];
            $apellidos = $row['apellidos'];
            $email = $row['email'];
            $telefono = $row['telefono'];
            $empresa = $row['empresa'];
            $dirección = $row['direccion'];
            $web = $row['web'];
            $linkedin = $row['linkedin'];
            $instagram = $row['instagram'];
            $facebook = $row['facebook'];
            $twitter = $row['twitter'];
            $fperfil = $row['fperfil'];
            $logo = $row['logo'];

            //Formateamos los datos Json para poder enviarselo a vcard.js 
            
            function obtenerDatosVCard($row) {
                $datos = [
                    'nombre' => $row['nombre'],
                    'apellidos' => $row['apellidos'],
                    'email' => $row['email'],
                    'telefono' => $row['telefono'],
                    'empresa' => $row['empresa'],
                    'direccion' => $row['direccion'],
                    'web' => $row['web'],
                    'linkedin' => $row['linkedin'],
                    'instagram' => $row['instagram'],
                    'facebook' => $row['facebook'],
                    'twitter' => $row['twitter'],
                    'fperfil' => $row['fperfil'],
                    'logo' => $row['logo']
                ];
                   // return $datos;
                header('Content-Type: application/json');
                echo json_encode($datos);
                }
                

        }else{
            echo "La vCard no se encuentra en la base de datos";
        }
```